# Insert points into a grid in R

Tags: r

I have a grid of the map of Porto, I would like to be able to insert in the grid the points to discretize them. In this way to see how many points are in each cell depending on the time.

This is the code of the grid:

```
#latitudS and longitudS are coordinates x Y
x = longitudS
y = latitudS

df = data.frame(x, y)


# Converting to a Spatial Points Data Frame so you can keep the value that you will change within the Grid
points = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = df[, 1:2], df)

# load some spatial data. Administrative Boundary
porto <- getData('GADM', country = 'Portugal', level = 2)
porto$NAME_1
porto <- porto[porto$NAME_2 == "Porto",]


# check the CRS to know which map units are used
proj4string(porto)
# "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Create a grid of points within the bbox of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# colorado with decimal degrees as map units
grid <- makegrid(porto, cellsize = 0.003) # cellsize in map units!

# grid is a data.frame. To change it to a spatial data set we have to
grid <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

portoWithin <-
  SpatialPixels(grid, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(porto)))

#### Converting the GRID to a Raster
ras_portoWithin <- raster(portoWithin)

## Assigning temporary values to the raster
values(ras_portoWithin) <- 0

## Using the Spatial point file created above to replace the values of the raster
r1 <- ras_portoWithin

plot(porto)
plot(portoWithin, add = T)
```

The idea is that for each cell the number of points will be output depending on the time in which the points have been recorded.
Also ask if there would be any way to transfer that grid to a leaflet, so you can see it on a map.

Thanks!